# Crawl webpart content

Tags: web-part, search, crawl

How can we crawl webpart content in SharePoint 2013? I would like to crawl content in a webpart, but I am unable to search content in webpart.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display webpart contents in search result then you have to Indexing ASPX Page Content. Following are the steps,

- On the site, click Settings > Site Settings.
- Under Search, click Search and offline availability.
- In the Indexing ASPX Page Content section, There are following 3 option and you have to select "Always index all Web Parts on this site" option.

**Do not index Web Parts if this site contains fine-grained permissions:**
When permissions of the ASPX page are different from the parent site, no content on the site appears in search results.

**Always index all Web Parts on this site:** Show content of all ASPX pages on the site in search results regardless of permissions.

**Never index any Web Parts on this site:** Hide content of all ASPX pages on the site from search results regardless of permissions.

[Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-content-on-a-site-to-be-searchable-2a420d01-4706-4d23-980e-c4c877113670)